# How to check if a TCP/IP server exists in Java

Tags: java, tcp

So I have created a simple TCP/IP server which is running in the background and I intend to only use it over LAN so I don't need to port forward. However I still need to know the IP in which the server is running from so I can connect from another computer on the LAN. Additionally I don't want to hard-code the IP into the program as I may sometimes want to change the computer which is running it.

I created this to check through all possible IPs on my LAN and check if there is a server running on it. (The outputs to the console were me just checking it was actually contacting the servers and so I can see the IPs were correct)

```
public void queryServers() {
    System.out.println("Querying servers...");
    String original192 = "192.168";
    for(int subOne = 0; subOne <= 255; subOne++) {
        for(int subTwo = 0; subTwo <= 255; subTwo++) {
            System.out.println("Querying " + original192 + "." + subOne + "." + subTwo + ":5050");
            String query = queryConnection(original192 + "." + subOne + "." + subTwo, 5050);
            if(!query.equals("-")) {
                System.out.println("Queried " + original192 + "." + subOne + "." + subTwo + ":5050 and received a response");
                Main.queriedServers.add(query);
            }else {
                System.out.println("Queried " + original192 + "." + subOne + "." + subTwo + ":5050 but could not connect");
            }
        }   
    }
}
```

This is basically getting my normal `192.168` part of my local IP address and then trying all the possible combinations of IPs that could go after it.

This is the function that actually tries to connect to the server. If it connects successfully, it sends back things like the host name and number of connected users to it.

```
public String queryConnection(String ip, int port) {
    try {
        clientSocket = new Socket(ip, port);
        out = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
        out.println("QUERY");
        String resp = in.readLine();
        return resp;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return "-";
    }
}
```

However this method takes a really long time because it will try multiple times to connect to the server before it decides that it can't reach and so in order to check all possible IPs, it would take probably hours.

This is a really inefficient way of doing it and I was wondering if there are any quicker ways or I would just have to stick with hard-coding the IP, which I'd rather avoid.

Comment: How about taking the server address as a parameter or configuration element like normal software? It's not exactly a smart idea to start mapping all internal IP addresses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I do  - I use a free dynamic dns services to map the server IP to a custom, but stable hostname. so when I use my server from another computer, I just change the IP address in the DNS service.

if you are creating your own server on your LAN, you can be more creative and use [multicasting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/datagrams/broadcasting.html) where your client can broadcast a datagram request to the whole LAN at once and server could respont with its IP address :) (some clustering protocols work this way)

Comment: @df778899 be aware of limitations of both options - TTL of the DNS records and some (virtualized) LANs won't allow multicast

Answer (score 0):

If everything is safely in a subnet (e.g. 192.168.x.x/255.255.0.0) multicast is quite a good option to allow client and server to find each other.

The Oracle Java tutorial is [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/datagrams/broadcasting.html).  Essentially the server can be on any IP it likes, but it also joins a known 'multicast IP' address (e.g. 203.0.113.0 in the tutorial).  This means it can receive and reply to small multicast packets (DatagramPackets).

The client could then send a DatagramPacket to that multicast IP and expect a reply from the server, maybe containing the real IP address to now connect to using normal sockets.

As mentioned at the start, this does need client and server to be in a single subnet, or related subnets that support multicast.  In my experience most do these days.